# CSS and deferred JS execution order

Tags: javascript, css

For example, I have a webpage with such structure in `<head>`, which is pretty common i guess:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> // here goes big css bundle
<script defer src="main.js"></script> // relatively small javascript bundle with defer attribute
```

And there is `<span id="element"></span>` on the page.

CSS bundle contains `#element { display: none; }`.
JS bundle contains (using jquery here):

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log($('#element').css('display'));
});
```

The result will be different from time to time. Sometimes JS executes earlier than CSS and the result is 'inline', sometimes JS executes later and the result is 'none' as I want it to be.

I want my JS bundle to be non-blocking so I use deffered attribute. I am not able to simply put my JS bundle in the end of a page because I use turbolinks and it [doesn't allow me to do it](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements).

`window:load` is not a best option too, because it will be fired when not only css but all resources will be downloaded including images.

So I want JS to be not-blocking and be executed after CSS to get consistent and predictable results. Maybe there is something I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution. You can just add a script without src attribute to the `<head>` with some code, an empty comment for example: `<script>//</script>`
And that's it. Now all the scripts, even deferred, will wait for styles to apply.
I'm not sure how it works, but I think deferred scripts are queued after a script without src which by standard must wait for css to apply.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a `load` event handler for the link element which will then insert the script into the head. Since the script is dynamically added, [it will automatically be `async`](/a/43413374/5764553). Therefore, it would be non-blocking and executed after the CSS is loaded.

```
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<script>
  var link = document.getElementById('stylesheet');

  link.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'main.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
</script>
```

However, this could cause you a problem. If the stylesheet is cached, then it might not emit a load event (because it's already loaded). For cases like that, you could [try checking for `link.sheet.cssRules`](/a/21147238/5764553).

Load events on `<link>` elements seem to [historically](/q/4488567/5764553) [be a](/q/14676049/5764553) [troublesome](/q/10537039/5764553) [issue](/q/3078584/5764553), so I don't know how well this will work.

[Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/maskedcoder/project/editor/XrBBYM) demonstrating the JS loading with a check for `link.sheet.cssRules`. It currently works for me in Chrome, FireFox, and Edge.

Comment: I've slightly modified your code and tested it in Chrome 64, Safari 11, Firefox 57 and the load event works nice. I guess there will be no problems with modern browsers, which is enough for me. Thank you very much, Andrew.

Comment: It turned out that this solution works badly with turbolinks, which I am using. And I accidentally found another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967081/css-and-deferred-js-execution-order/49029391#49029391